# Is there a way to put a Tailwind Object in a Pydantic Basemodel

Tags: python, tailwind-css, pydantic

Since I have to manage many different Tailwind Objects for a project I want to to have the organized in a Basemodel. Integer, Floats and bools work great but it does not accept Tailwind.

```
class Text_BM(BaseModel):
    header_style = Tailwind().text_color('black').font_weight('bold').font_size("6xl").font_style("italic") 
    
text = Text_BM()
```

Error:
`RuntimeError: no validator found for <class 'nicegui.tailwind.Tailwind'>, see` arbitrary_types_allowed `in Config`

Any Solutions?
Thank you in advance :)